# Заменить домен у файла

Tags: домен

Есть сайт, у него на сервере лежит файл, доступный по ссылке **http://site.net/file.mp3**
Есть еще один сайт **http://my.ru/** нужно чтобы ссылки на файлы первого сайта, были с доменом второго сайта. То есть, человек чтобы видел уже **http://my.ru/file.mp3** файл.

Файл лежит на файловом хостинге, качать к себе на сервер где лежит сайт, нет смысла, нужно быстрый доступ к большому количеству файлов, при этом чтобы файлы качались по прямой ссылке, без задержек.

Подсказывали что подобное можно реализовать через прокси, но думал, искал, и ничего путнего не нашел.

Прошу совета, примера, возможно кто-то встречал что-то подобное в интернете.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если эти два сайта твои (взаимосвязаны) - тогда не подскажу. Но если http://site.net/file.mp3 "любой" сайт, то что мешает составить список "параметр - значение" и вначале скачивать мр3 в директорию своего сайта, а затем отдавать клиенту (можно поставить "красивую картинку" закачки). Но скорей всего я не понял вопрос...

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Скачивать не могу, так как одновременно смотреть файлы могут тысячи пользователей, если каждый файл качать, то задержка может нарастать и теряется смысл в этом вообще.

Answer (score 1):

В случае если `site.net` совершенно сторонний ресурс, не предусматривающий отдачу контента с других доменов и вы хотите, что бы при скачивании файла оставалась ссылка на `http://my.ru/file.mp3`, то единственный способ - это проксировать запрос через свой сервер. Однако, при этом *весь трафик все-равно будет идти через ваш сервер*, по этому этот вариант даже хуже, чем хранить контент на своем сервере.

Если же вам достаточно, что бы ссылки только указывали на `http://my.ru/file.mp3`, но при переходе по ним отображался сайт `site.net`, то можно делать редирект. В этом случае весь трафик будет идти минуя ваш сервер. 
Редирект делается при помощи [HTTP заголовка Location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) и кода ответа 30х.
Т.е., к примеру, по запросу `http://my.ru/file.mp3` вам нужно будет отдавать следующмй ответ:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 OK
Location: http:/site.net/file.mp3
```

И последний вариант, если `site.net` предоставляет пользователям возможность использовать  свои alias'ы доменных имен для своего сервиса (например, как это сделано в [Amazon S3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs)), то вы можете создать поддомен, к примеру, `media.my.ru` с [`CNAME`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) записью указывающей на `site.net`. В этом случае, вы сможете создавать ссылки `http://media.my.ru/file.mp3`, которые будут напрямую вести на `http://site.net/file.mp3`

Comment: 1й не совсем понял механизм, но с большим трафиком мне не подходит. 3й тоже не подходит, alias`ов, там нет. Остается второй, думаю он и будет верным, попробую, если выйдет приму как правильный. Спс.

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал редиректом, зеркала хорошо, но когда один сайт - один: ещё лучше

Comment: Можете подкинуть пример, на любом языке, я себе переведу на python, или подробнее механизм, я просто представить сам механизм не могу.